# JMH Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jmh

I'm not able to run simple JMH benchmark inside eclipse.
Maven dependencies:

```xml
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmh-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.12</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
                <version>1.12</version>
            </dependency>
```

**Java code:**

```java
    public class BTest {
        @Benchmark
        public void test() {
            // todo
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
            Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                     .include(BTest.class.getSimpleName())
                      .build();
    
            new Runner(opt).run();
        }
    }
```

**Result of run:**

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ERROR: Unable
> to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList     at
> org.openjdk.jmh.runner.AbstractResourceReader.getReaders(AbstractResourceReader.java:96)
>   at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.BenchmarkList.find(BenchmarkList.java:104)
>   at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.internalRun(Runner.java:256)   at
> org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:206)    at
> com.test.BTest.main(BTest.java:24)
```

Maybe the problem is, that I'm running it from eclipse.

Comment: Have you tried not running it in eclipse? Since you mentioned it, it would make sense to try it

Comment: @WillBarnwell not yet...

Comment: [here](https://github.com/artyushov/idea-jmh-plugin/issues/13#issuecomment-95628473) may be an answer for idea

Comment: @NanoNova not working

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally found it out.
There was a problem with missing `exec-maven-plugin` plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>run-benchmarks</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <classpath />
                    <argument>org.openjdk.jmh.Main</argument>
                    <argument>.*</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Weirdly, for Scala + Maven, I had to add this in to even get the error you have above ... : https://github.com/bbarker/scala-maven-jmh-bench-demo/tree/89481477d6d051c038eabbb16ce6c14212844b8d

Answer (score 28):

If anyone is using Gradle, add the [jmh-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/melix/jmh-gradle-plugin) to your plugins block:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'me.champeau.jmh' version '0.6.8'
}
```

Then add all of the following in your dependencies block (check the latest version of JMH [on Maven here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.jmh/jmh-core)):

```
dependencies {
    jmh 'org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-core:1.36'
    jmh 'org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-generator-annprocess:1.36'

    // this is the line that solves the missing /META-INF/BenchmarkList error
    jmhAnnotationProcessor 'org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-generator-annprocess:1.36'
}
```

Then just use the following to run your benchmarks through Gradle:

```bash
./gradlew jmh
```

### Running through your IDE

If you also want to run the benchmarks from within your IDE instead of through Gradle, you can do either of the following:

#### Option 1 - `main` method

Just use a main method with no additional configuration and your IDE will respect your annotation configuration:

```java
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Fork(value = 1)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, time = 5000)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, time = 5000)
public class MyBenchmark {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options options = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(MyBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
            .build();
        new Runner(options).run();
    }

    // benchmarks omitted
}
```

#### Option 2 - Install JMH Plugin

If you're using IntelliJ, install the [JMH Java Microharness Benchmark Plugin](https://github.com/artyushov/idea-jmh-plugin) from the `Preferences > Plugins` section, then you can omit your `main` method altogether and IntelliJ will give you a run button next to your class name:

[image: JMH benchmark in IntelliJ]

Comment: Why doesn't the plugin just set these things for you?

Comment: `jmhAnnotationProcessor` is not required. If fact, none of the things shown in the `dependencies` block are required unless you want to change the version.

Comment: As opposed to previous comment, without those dependencies, the JMH plugin for intelliJ produces the errors listed in the question

Answer (score 9):

pom.xml must have the below dependencies and configurations to Java Micro-benchmark Harness (JMH) Framework

```
<properties>
    <jmh.version>1.21</jmh.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmh-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jmh.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
    <version>${jmh.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>java-jmh</finalName>
<plugins>
    <plugin>    
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <path>
                    <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
                    <version>${jmh.version}</version>
                </path>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>run-benchmarks</id>
                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath />
                        <argument>org.openjdk.jmh.Main</argument>
                        <argument>.*</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

After this go to command line and run the command $mvn clean install

Answer (score 5):

This could happen when your compiler plugin has not processed the JMH related annotations. For me, [Gill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53928409/9845110) with the `maven-compiler-plugin`'s `<annotationProcessorPaths>` update worked.

Answer (score 4):

I realized that I already had `exec-maven-plugin` in my parent pom as mentioned in expected answer but I had to run `mvn clean install` as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40748670 to fix the error

Answer (score 4):

Having had the same error; and running the tests from maven or intellij didn't work. I realised that the problem was that I wrote the benchmark in Kotlin. Changing the code to java sorted the issue.

Comment: I banged my head against this error for hours trying to write a `@Benchmark` in Kotlin to no avail. Once I flipped to Java it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add version as well. This works for me

```
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error using the Intelij Idea's [JMH Java Microharness Benchmark Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7529-jmh-java-microbenchmark-harness) and you also using Gradle try changing the default running task from Gradle to Intelij Idea. To do this:

**Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle**

Change **Build and Run using** to **Intelij IDEA**

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above solution. I ended using [jmh-maven-plugin](https://github.com/metlos/jmh-maven-plugin):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>pw.krejci</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmh-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

and I run it with:

```
mvn clean install jmh:benchmark
```

It seems that it does *not* require exec-maven-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin or maven-shade-plugin.

**Notice** that the benchmarks must be in the **test package**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's everything I had to add to `pom.xml` fix mine.
This snippet ended up pretty close to [Ishaq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62983884/11705601) minus a few extras and name-specifics.
I hope this is just a cleaner and easier to readily-use answer.

```xml
  <properties>
    <jmh.version>1.36</jmh.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
      <artifactId>jmh-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jmh.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
      <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
      <version>${jmh.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>benchmarks</finalName>
              <transformers>
                <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>org.openjdk.jmh.Main</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```