# JMH doesn't run inside a Java Module (Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList)

Tags: java, maven, java-module, jmh

I took a project that uses `maven-surefire-plugin` (automated tests) to trigger JMH benchmarks and added `module-info.java` to it. Now, `META-INF/BenchmarkList` is no longer getting generated (in fact, the entire directory is missing) so I end up with the following error when launching the benchmarks:

`ERROR: Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList`

I suspect that Java Modules is preventing the annotation processor from running properly, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: In general, it's really tough to figure out the error or its cause when there is not an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the question though. Just sharing this since the question starts with maven-surefire and the answer ends it with maven-compiler instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured it out through trial and error. It looks like a bug (or "feature") in maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.0. When `module-info.java` is present, the JMH annotation processor is no longer picked up automatically. Adding this configuration fixed the problem for me:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    [...]
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
                <version>${jmh.version}</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    [...]
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**UPDATE**: I filed a [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-369) against maven-compiler-plugin.

Comment: Worked for me too after mvn clean install.

Comment: what is the value of  jmh.version?

Comment: @LizLamperouge Whatever version of JMH you want to use.